# Does this property of probability distributions have a name?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on the paper where we require for our distributions to be somewhat dense even at very small left-tail values. 
The idea is that the CDF of our distribution should grow, from the very beginning, at least linearly (or polynomialy) fast; here's a definition.

Take a probability distribution $\mathcal P$ on a non-negative sample space with a cumulative distribution function $F:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \left[0,1\right]$. You may assume that $\mathcal P$ have a finite mean and variance, but I don't think this is relevant. 
I am interested in the following particular property:

> We say that $\mathcal P$ have a *thick left tail*, iff. 
>   there exists $c>0$ such that for any positive $x<c$ we have  $F\left(x\right)>x$.

Of course, the name is made up; hence the question for the probability people here: **Is there a better name for such a property?**

In our actual case we don't require CDF to be linearly steep; the actual property that I'm interested in would be stated as

> We say that $\mathcal P$ have a *$q$-thick left tail*, iff. 
>   there exists $c>0$ such that for any positive $x<c$ we have  $F\left(x\right)>x^q$.

Any ideas are most welcome!

Comment: What is the property here? $\lim_{x\to0}F(x)$ does not depend on $x$, but $x^c$ does. Anyhow, I'd be surprised if there is a name for any such property.

Comment: I guess they both goes to 0 as $x$ goes to 0, and the property is characterizing the rate at which $F$ goes to 0 as $x$ goes to 0.

Comment: Thans for both good comments; I edited the question accordingly so that it makes more sense now.